# Piranha CMS Management Custom Controller Not Found

Tags: piranha-cms

I am having an issue with adding a custom controller to my Piranha CMS.
I have set up a new site and installed from the template and all the base functionality is working well.
I have added the menu to the manager section using the following code from the documentation:

```
        Manager.Menu.Add(new Manager.MenuGroup()
        {
            InternalId = "MEProducts",
            Name = "Products"
        });

        Manager.Menu.Where(m => m.InternalId == "MEProducts").Single().Items =
           new List<Manager.MenuItem>() {
            new Manager.MenuItem() {
              Name = "Products",
              Action = "productlist",
              Controller = "products",
              Permission = "ADMIN",
              SelectedActions = "productlist,productedit"
            },
            new Manager.MenuItem() {
              Name = "Product groups",
              Action = "productgrouplist",
              Controller = "products",
              Permission = "ADMIN",
              SelectedActions = "productgrouplist,productgroupedit"
            }
          };
```

This menu displays in the manager interface fine, the problem is when I click on the menu item the controller path can not be found.

The controller is class is in Areas/Manager/Controllers/ProductsController.cs and the code is below

```
namespace MyApp.Areas.Manager.Controllers
{
public class ProductsController : ManagerController
{
    //
    // GET: /Manager/Products/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult ProductList()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult ProductEdit(string id = "")
    {
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

There are view files for `ProductList` and `ProductEdit` in Areas/Manager/Views/Products/

My web config contains the following line that I believe I need

```
<add key="manager_namespaces" value="MyApp.Areas.Manager.Controllers" />
```

When I click on the Products link in the manager I get

> The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>   Requested URL: /MyApp/manager/products/productlist

The page /MyApp/manager/page displays fine for the default configuration.

I am sure that I have missed something, or done something incorrect somewhere I'm just not sure where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried reproduce your issues but it works perfectly with your productscontroller in my project. I've zipped my test-project and uploaded it to my dropbox so you can download and compare it to your project:

**EDIT**
*Removed download link as author downloaded the file*

Please let me know when you've downloaded the zip-file so I can delete it.

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Downloaded thank you. Your test project works perfectly, I will use that to work out what is wrong with mine. Thank you very much for that.

Comment: Great, when you find out what was causing the error, let me know if the documentation needs to be clarified somewhere!

Comment: If anyone is interested I found what I did wrong. On http://piranhacms.org/docs/extend/custom-entities it states to use
    <appSettings>
       <add key="manager_namespaces" value="MyApp.Controllers" />
    </appSettings>
But really it needs to be in 
  <piranha>
    <settings>
      <managerNamespaces value="MyApp.Areas.Manager.Controllers" />

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the docs and fixed the issue. The documentation was outdated and refered to an earlier version.